# MongoDB connection problem on a private network

Tags: mongodb

I have started mongodb instances on two ubuntu nodes. Mongodb servers listen on the private IP address of each machine. the two machines are in different networks but manages to communicate well.

```
Machine A (db1 10.20.106.12)
Machine B (db2 10.1.0.192)
```

On each of the machines I can connect with the mongo shell. but from machine A i can't connect to  machine B mongod and vice versa. However, the port is open on the firewall, there is no authentication on the mongod deamon and a telnet or a netcat on the port shows that the ports is open.

I am at the end of my debugging. in the logs we notice that at each connection attempt of a peer there a socket is opened and immediately closed:

```
    2020-12-19T11: 04: 08.984 + 0000 I NETWORK [listener] connection accepted from 10.1.0.192:48352 # 5 (1 connection now open)
    2020-12-19T11: 04: 08.985 + 0000 I NETWORK [conn5] end connection 10.1.0.192:48352 (0 connections now open)
```

In the screenshot below I am doing obvious tests to show you my problem.

[image]

How i started mongodb instances on each nodes ?

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb2 --replSet rs1 --bind_ip localhost,host_private_ip
```

Thank you for your contributions

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: What is "host_private_ip"? Try bindIpAll

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it is ip of my host. Il you like in the picture you will see the value of ip addrr show